# Why does the HTML I fetch with wget look different from what I see in browser?

Tags: unix, web-scraping, wget

I use wget to download the HMTL, but what I get is different from what I see in the browser. Particularly, I am interested in the latitude of the location

```
wget "http://m.yp.com/30332/pep-boys?page=0"
grep 'data-lat=' pep-boys\?page\=0
```

... NO RESULTS :(((

Comment: 1/ Improve formating 2/ This should belong to another website.

Comment: Dear AsTeR, thank you for your recommendations. For the future, could you please recommend me a website where I can ask web-scrapping questions. Thanks!

Comment: There's the superuser and serverfault community (they're based on the same system as Stack Overflow, your post might be moved to them if Im not the only one to flag it). Moderators might also do not agree and let your post here, that's a minor problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible reason is that your headers aren't the same than those your brother so the webserver doesn't behave the same way.

Give a look at this : http://www.askapache.com/linux/wget-header-trick.html